# How to track progress in MongoDB Realm on initial sync?

Tags: .net, mongodb, synchronization, realm

I'm planning to develop a Windows application with an offline-first approach. I found MongoDB Realm with the .Net SDK that seems to suit my requirements. Currently I'm trying to find out how I can track the upload/download progress when connecting to the server database (especially for the first time).

I connect like this:

```
config = new SyncConfiguration("myPart", user); 
var realm = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync(config);
```

Then I found this snippet in the Realm documentation to track for example the download-progress:

```
var token = session.GetProgressObservable(ProgressDirection.Download, ProgressMode.ReportIndefinitely)
                   .Subscribe(progress =>
                   {
                       if (progress.TransferredBytes < progress.TransferableBytes)
                       {
                           // Show progress indicator
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           // Hide the progress indicator
                       }
                   });
```

The problem for me is, that I need to have a session-handle to subscribe to the progress event. But I can get the session only after I opened the realm (with `realm.GetSession()`). And as I open the realm async I will not get the realm before `Realm.GetInstanceAsync(config)` is completed, which makes the progress-tracker useless.

What can I do to get the progress during the sync? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify SyncConfiguration's [`OnProgress`](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/dotnet/10.0.0-beta.1/reference/Realms.Sync.SyncConfiguration.html#Realms_Sync_SyncConfiguration_OnProgress) property:

```
config = new SyncConfiguration("myPart", user)
{
     OnProgress = progress =>
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {progress.TransferredBytes}/{progress. TransferableBytes}");
     }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the synchronous `realm.GetInstance` method and immediately register the progress observable:

```
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);
realm.GetSession().GetProgressObservable(...)
```

The `OnProgess` property is equivalent to `ProgressDirection.Download` and `ProgressMode.ForCurrentlyOutstandingWork`.